# Replacing the values in sql table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
OrderID, OrderTime, OrderItem

1,       1 am,      Orange
1,       2 am,      Apple
2,       3 am,      Grape
3,       2 am,      Apple
3,       3 am,      Coconut
1,       5 am,      Banana
1,       6 am,      Apple
```

The above is the original table. The below is the table I want. if the order id is the same for continuously, I wwant to change the order time to the minimum time.

```
OrderID, OrderTime, OrderItem

1,       1 am,      Orange
1,       1 am,      Apple
2,       3 am,      Grape
3,       2 am,      Apple
3,       2 am,      Coconut
1,       5 am,      Banana
1,       5 am,      Apple
```

Comment: @william, what is type for column OrderTime?

Comment: "continuously" as ordered by what?

Comment: datetime is the type of that column. as order by order ID

Comment: @william - If you order `OrderId` by `OrderId` then none of them will have any gaps in the sequence at all! You need some other column to order by. e.g. `OrderItemId`

Comment: Nope.. But the order time of the sixth row is defnitely larger than the second row.

Comment: @william - There is no "natural" order to your data in SQL Server if you don't specify an order then the order you get back is in no way guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "natural" order to your data in SQL Server if you don't specify an order then the order you get back is in no way guaranteed. You need a column that you can use to define an `order by`. Once you have this you can do something like

```
declare @data table 
(
OrderItemId int identity(1,1) primary key,
OrderID int, 
OrderTime datetime, 
OrderItem varchar(10))

insert into @data
SELECT 1,'00:01:00','Orange' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'00:01:00','Apple' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'00:03:00','Grape' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'00:02:00','Apple' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'00:02:00','Coconut' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'00:05:00','Banana' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'00:05:00','Apple';

WITH cte1 AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY OrderItemId)-
ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderItemId) AS Grp
FROM @data
), cte2 AS
(
SELECT *, MIN(OrderTime) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID, Grp) AS MinOrderTime
FROM cte1
)
UPDATE cte2 SET OrderTime = MinOrderTime

SELECT OrderID,convert(varchar, OrderTime, 8) OrderItemId, OrderItem
 FROM @data
 ORDER BY OrderItemId
```